# Parsing string to pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Suppose I have the memory address as a string representation (say "0x27cd10"). How can I convert this to a pointer (void*)?

i.e.

```
int main() {
     const char* address = "0x29cd10";
     void* p;

     // I want p to point to address 0x29cd10 now...

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know the address of some memory already before compile-time?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do that? What's the scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strtol` lets you specify the base (16, for hexadecimal, or 0 to auto-detect based on the `0x` prefix in the input) when parsing the string.  Once you have the pointer stored as an integer, just use `reinterpret_cast` to form the pointer.

Comment: Mine didn't convert from hex.  Good catch

Comment: Example please?

Answer (score 4):

```
sscanf(address, "%p", (void **)&p);
```

No need for strtol or reinterpret_cast (which is C++ anyway and no good in C only).

Comment: Well, `(void **)` is `reinterpret_cast<>` in this case.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin `p` is `void*`, thus `&p` is `void**`, meaning the cast does nothing at all. You can use `reinterpret_cast<>` for an `implicit_cast<>`, but that's overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
std::string adr = "0x7fff40602780";
unsigned long b = stoul(address, nullptr, 16);
int *ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(b);
```

If you want to convert a string address to an object pointer, here is another example:

```
std::string adr= "0x7fff40602780";
unsigned long b= stoul(adr, nullptr, 16);
unsigned long *ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(b);
Example *converted = reinterpret_cast<Example*>(ptr);
```